# Проблема с парсингом тик ток на Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Час добрый.
Имеется скрипт по парсингу тик тока, который все время прилежно работал без всяких сбоев, писал сам.
Но сегодня во время запуска начала вылазить ошибка, как я понял связанная с возможно новой защитой от ботов у тик тока.
Суть в том, что после выполнения запроса (весь код будет ниже со скринами ответов) выдает фразу "Unsupported path(Janus)". Проверив другими библиотеками (aiohttp), мне выдало что к ссылке добавляется %0A, при переходе на которую мы и получаем "Unsupported path(Janus)". Попробовал обрезать последние три элемента в ссылке, использовав подобное "url[:-3]", но в таком случае сразу же кидало на страницу со скриптом верификации (ссылка на пасту с полученным ответом https://pastebin.com/r276fZKt). И суть проблемы в том, что не выдает нужный результат. Если получать html обычными реквестами + bs, то в ответе выдает просто пустоту. В то время как то что ниже, выдавало раньше всю инфу о странице, где я обрезая лишнее мог получить нужный мне ответ.
Помогите пожалуйста советом/кодом как можно решить данную проблему. Нужная мне информация - кол-во подписок пользователя.
Код парсера не особо удобно было вставлять, скинул его на пасту(https://pastebin.com/RBhenZuu).
Входные данные имеют следующий вид: "548435054;[https://tiktok.com/@satu388"](https://tiktok.com/@satu388%22)

Comment: Если бы не последняя ссылка в жизни бы не догадался, что тт - это тикток. Зачем вы экономите буквы? )

Comment: Извиняюсь, сейчас исправлю) Привычка просто)